# GCC and AMD Ryzen

Tags: kernel, gcc, amd

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen#GCC
says, neither GCC 6.x nor GCC 7 is Ryzen optimized.
But, when doing man gcc-7 I clearly see march=znver1 is available in GCC-7. Or is this just a dummy option doing nothing? I´d like to use march=znver1 to get my kernel a bit more optimized for my Ryzen 2500U.
In my distro there is actually GCC-9 and GCC-10 available, I could upgrade from 7 to 9 or 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`znver1` was added to GCC [in 2015](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=9ce29eb05de83246802a03873ae1a6aaeae8e598), and included in GCC 6.1. It has always provided some level of tuning for Zen CPUs (see [the cost tables in that first commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blobdiff;f=gcc/config/i386/i386.c;h=38953ddc4aec4c2ee7b8d847dda725deacc8d367;hp=d59b59b1cd5bc68e30d086f7cd58c71579f18c21;hb=9ce29eb05de83246802a03873ae1a6aaeae8e598;hpb=0580f6a1a8eba90a82c83b8341f94d25529b25e9)), but the Phoronix benchmarks quoted by the Gentoo wiki suggest that that wasn’t particularly effective at the time.

In general, when it comes to compiler support and optimisation for “newer” architectures, newer releases of the compiler are better — optimisation improvements are rarely back-ported, and they take time to be developed in the compilers. This includes the many patches which have helped improved the performance of code generated for Zen CPUs (look for [patches by Jan Hubicka](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=Jan%20Hubicka) in particular). As always when it comes to performance, you should benchmark the scenarios you care about.